# Achieving consistent branding for all SharePoint 2013 sites

Tags: 2013, master-page, branding, custom-masterpage, design

I see that a lot of the discussions and documentation tend to be focused on branding solutions for publishing sites and understandably so. We have a lot of other types of sites too (e.g. communities, team sites) so it'd be great to have a branding solution that can be applied across the board.

Is this achievable with a single master page or would it be better to have separate master pages for different types of sites?

The guys over at http://responsivesharepoint.codeplex.com/ have gone for one solution for publishing sites and one for other sites.

Is that the way to go?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Branding in SharePoint essentially has two sides to it: 1) Publishing and 2) Everything Else.  Not only are there are a lot of specific features that come with Publishing but those sites also usually have very different requirements in terms of the way content is managed on the site.  They also tend to have dramatically different audiences as well.

Since the two camps are so different, it is generally best to have two different Master Pages.  They can be very similar, of course.

Comment: Thanks for your reply - would you mind going into a little more detail? I understand that the two sides (as you describe them) are looking to achieve different things but the audience in an intranet scenario are still the same set of users and as such it seems important to provide a consistent 'chrome' and if possible a well designed IA that takes both sides into account. Creating multiple master pages would introduce some duplication. I guess I'm keen to get a deeper understanding of the concerns that make that duplication the better option.

Answer (score 0):

Bind tuning have the tool where you need to brand all the sharepoint sites. with several master pages per theme you can apply the same look and fell across all the sharepoint sites, team sites, publishing sites, search sites, even the public facing sites and the news feed. take a look at http://www.bindtuning.com this works for the 2007, 2010 and 2013 version of the SharePoint and office 365